# Create a boolean column if one of the columns is greater than 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I want to set up two conditions

I want to return all columns with col1 == 0 and col7 == True

```
    col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 False   True
1   0.0 0.0 4.0 0.0 0.0 True    False
2   0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 False   True
```

I wrote this code, but it says I need to use any() or all(). I don't think any() conditions works in here. I just need to set up the conditions. Anyway to fix this code?

```
print((df['col1'] == 0 and df['col7'] == False).sum())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out data in pandas by assigning each row a True or False value. Rows that are given true will remain in the dataframe and the others will be removed.

In your case, you can use the code

```
df = df[(df['col1'] == 0) & (df['col7'])]
```

Note that what we're doing here is creating two boolean arrays with each of your conditions, wrapping them in parens, and then using the & operator to take the element wise AND.

Another thing you could try is using [Mito](https://trymito.io?source=stackoverflow) (disclaimer, I'm a dev of it). It's a spreadsheet that lets you write common Excel formulas, and then generates the pandas code for you. In your case, you could use the formula, IF(AND(col1 == 1, col7), 'keep', 'remove'), and then use the point and click filter functionality to remove all of the rows labelled with 'remove'.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.any()`:

```
code = ['col2', 'col3', 'col4']
df['bool_col'] = df[code].gt(0).any(1)
```

Comment: sorry could you explain a little more?